# Evaluating string/combination of variables as logical expression in oracle pl/sql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

In my Pl/Sql code , I have three variables v_var1 , v_operand , v_var2 whose values are populated based on some logic (v_var1 & v_var2 can be date , number , varchar. Associated Operand will be according to data type only). A sample would be 
`v_var1 = 10 , v_operand = '=' , v_var2 = 20`.
Based on these value , I have to evaluate whether the condition `"v_var1   -v_operand-   v_var2"`is true or false.

Ex :- with above values, I have to evaluate whether 10 equals 20 or not.

How can I achieve this ? Can I pass the whole string as '10 = 20' to some function and get the result as false?

One way I can think of is to write CASE statements for evaluating but can there be a better way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL to do the evaluation as a filter on the `dual` table:

```
declare
  v_var1 varchar2(10) := '10';
  v_operand varchar2(10) := '=';
  v_var2 varchar2(10) := '20';

  l_result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from dual where :var1 ' || v_operand || ' :var2'
    into l_result using v_var1, v_var2;

  if l_result = 1 then
    dbms_output.put_line('True');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('False');
  end if;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

False
```

If the condition is true the count will get 1, otherwise it will get 0, and you can then test that via the local variable you select the count into.

Holding dates and numbers as strings isn't ideal, even temporarily, but might be OK as long as you convert to/from the real data types consistently, e.g. always explicitly converting dates with `to_date` and `to_char` and specifying the format masks.

Comment: Thanks Alex !! This is what I needed .